How Langchain StructuredTool works with function with more complex signature
I am working on a ChatBOT that leverages a ReAct Agent to perform some operations. To show my problem I created this small example taking inspiration from the official documentation.
I was able to run LangChain with tools decorated with the @tool tag. This tool assumes you have a string as input (Action Input) and output. Parsing this string I can run the tool, get back the reply to the LLM, and have something that more or less works.
My problem is the "more or less". If I want to promote code in production I need code can work 99.9999% of the time, not 50%.
For this reason, I decided to move to StructuredTool with Pydantic schema as you can see in the example.
However, when I ran it against LLama 3.1 (on my Mac) with the Ollama CLI I got this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sasadangelo/github.com/sasadangelo/chatterpy/experiments/multiply.py", line 59, in <module>
    agent_executor.invoke({"input": "Can you multiply 3 by 2 and give me the result?"})
  File "/Users/sasadangelo/github.com/sasadangelo/chatterpy/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/langchain/chains/base.py", line 164, in invoke
    raise e
  File "/Users/sasadangelo/github.com/sasadangelo/chatterpy/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/langchain/chains/base.py", line 154, in invoke
    self._call(inputs, run_manager=run_manager)
  File "/Users/sasadangelo/github.com/sasadangelo/chatterpy/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/langchain/agents/agent.py", line 1625, in _call
    next_step_output = self._take_next_step(
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/sasadangelo/github.com/sasadangelo/chatterpy/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/langchain/agents/agent.py", line 1331, in _take_next_step
    [
  File "/Users/sasadangelo/github.com/sasadangelo/chatterpy/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/langchain/agents/agent.py", line 1416, in _iter_next_step
    yield self._perform_agent_action(
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/sasadangelo/github.com/sasadangelo/chatterpy/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/langchain/agents/agent.py", line 1438, in _perform_agent_action
    observation = tool.run(
                  ^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/sasadangelo/github.com/sasadangelo/chatterpy/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/langchain_core/tools/base.py", line 586, in run
    raise error_to_raise
  File "/Users/sasadangelo/github.com/sasadangelo/chatterpy/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/langchain_core/tools/base.py", line 549, in run
    tool_args, tool_kwargs = self._to_args_and_kwargs(tool_input)
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/sasadangelo/github.com/sasadangelo/chatterpy/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/langchain_core/tools/base.py", line 472, in _to_args_and_kwargs
    tool_input = self._parse_input(tool_input)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/sasadangelo/github.com/sasadangelo/chatterpy/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/langchain_core/tools/base.py", line 420, in _parse_input
    input_args.validate({key_: tool_input})
  File "/Users/sasadangelo/github.com/sasadangelo/chatterpy/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pydantic/main.py", line 1361, in validate
    return cls.model_validate(value)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/sasadangelo/github.com/sasadangelo/chatterpy/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pydantic/main.py", line 568, in model_validate
    return cls.__pydantic_validator__.validate_python(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
pydantic_core._pydantic_core.ValidationError: 2 validation errors for MultiplyInput
a
  Input should be a valid integer, unable to parse string as an integer [type=int_parsing, input_value='{"a": 3, "b": 2', input_type=str]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.8/v/int_parsing
b
  Field required [type=missing, input_value={'a': '{"a": 3, "b": 2'}, input_type=dict]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.8/v/missing 

Debugging the code here is the prompt that arrives at the LLM:
Human: 
    Answer the following questions as best you can. You have access to the following tools:

    multiply(a: int, b: int) -> int - This function multiplies two integers and returns an integer.

    Use the following format:

    Question: the input question you must answer
    Thought: you should always think about what to do
    Action: the action to take, should be one of [multiply].
    Action Input: the input to the action (in dictionary format).
    Observation: always analyze the result of the action.
    ... (this Thought/Action/Action Input/Observation could repeat N times until you don't find the final answer)
    Thought: I now know the final answer.
    Final Answer: the final answer to the original input question

    Begin!

    Question: Can you multiply 3 by 2 and give me the result?
    Thought: 

Here is the LLM reply:
Question: Can you multiply 3 by 2 and give me the result?
Thought: I need to perform a multiplication operation on two integers.
Action: multiply
Action Input: {"a": 3, "b": 2

It seems that the Thought and Action are OK. The input is strange (a curly brace is missing). However, not every run gives the same result. Sometimes I get Action: Multiply or Action: Multiply + additional words. Sometimes it goes in an infinite loop until max iteration is reached.
Can anyone help me to understand what's wrong with my code? How can I make it functional and stable?
